# newbie: how to pass User to Asset model for custom method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, inheritance, activerecord, models

Trying to use current_user.id (devise) inside my asset model, only current_user.id isn't available. How do I make current_user.id available in my Asset model? ( passing user to asset model somehow?)

```
  after_save :set_photo

  def set_photo
    user = User.find_by_id(1)
    # user = User.find_by_id(current_user.id)  <-- should be this
    user.has_photo = true
    user.save
  end
```

Comment: You cannot access current user in your model, as it is a helper method provided by devise. If you google 'using current_user in model', you'll find a solution that implements multiple thread but I personally refrain from doing that, especially if I am using ActiveRecord as it can clash with AR's connection pools.

Comment: Btw, can you elaborate on what you are trying to do. I can understand that you'd want to set `has_photo` field to true for current user, if any asset object is saved. What are you using Asset for, is it associated to User ? If you want a simple straightforward solution then in `assets#create` and `assets#update`, you can simply update `has_photo` field for `current_user`(you can create an instance method in User if you wish so) if the create or update is successful.

Comment: Assets belongs to User yes, Perhaps Its indeed better to just use the controller create and update actions, Assets are carrierwave attached images, then only - how would one detect in the update action if an asset is removed? thx

Comment: "how would one detect in the update action if an asset is removed".. what do you mean by that ? By remove do you mean deleting an asset or are you talking of some sort of form where a user can add or remove images ?

Comment: Hmm..so, Asset belongs to User. Then, User has one(or many) assets. So, you are allowing current user to create an asset, right? I am sorry, but I need some more information on the entire scenario to be able to suggest something more concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `current_user` in a callback chain within your model scope. This is because `current_user` is a property of the request-response cycle. Also, having to use `current_user` in your model almost certainly means your database design is inadequate or wrong.

For e.g. in your case, why are you trying to update an attribute of a `User` when `Asset` is updated? That is a certain code smell unless they are related.

A couple of things you can try:

1. Correct the DB design problem - Define an association between `Asset` and `User`. You can then do `@asset.user = current_user` (or something to this effect) in your controllers.
2. Ugly, brute force method: Do not depend on callbacks and explicitly call your method in your controllers.